# Run-time optimization in Python for-loop and meshgrid with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, numba, cpython

This post is similar to a question I already posted a few weeks ago but the run-time that I currently have is not really good.
I have to implement this rule :

```html
<img src="https://render.githubusercontent.com/render/math?math=w_{ij}^{\sigma}=w_{ij}^{\sigma-1}%2b\frac{1}{N}(p_i^{\sigma}p_j^{\sigma}-p_i^{\sigma}h_{ji}^{\sigma}-p_j^{\sigma}h_{ij}^{\sigma}))"> 
where <img src="https://render.githubusercontent.com/render/math?math=h_{ij} = \sum_{k:i\neq k\neq j}w_{ik}^{\sigma-1}p_{k}^{\sigma}">
```

I ended up with this piece of code:

```
def rule(samples):

M, N = samples.shape
w = np.zeros((N,N))


for sigma in range(M):
    H = np.zeros((N,N))
    
    w_with_diag_zeros = w - np.diag(np.diag(w)) #Exclusion of cases where i == k and shape of (2500, 2500)
    sigma_th_samples_broadcast = samples[sigma] + np.zeros((N, N)) #Exclusion of cases where k == j
    samples_with_diag_zeros = ( sigma_th_samples_broadcast 
                                - np.diag(np.diag(sigma_th_samples_broadcast)) ) #(2500, 2500)
    #Matrix H
    H = np.matmul(w_with_diag_zeros, np.transpose(samples_with_diag_zeros))
    
    #For the w matrix
    p_i, p_j = np.meshgrid(samples[sigma], samples[sigma]) #p_j = p_i shape also (2500, 2500)
    
    w += (1/N) * (p_i * p_j 
                     - p_j * H.T
                     - p_i * H)  #shapes of p_j*H.t = p_i*H = (2500, 2500)
    
return w
```

samples is a 2D-array of shape (M, N). More importantly, with M = 50 and N = 2500, creating a matrix with this function takes about 40seconds to 1min. I tried numpa, cpython, others definitions but none of these solutions provided a better result. My question is, is there a way to optimize this function further ?

Comment: Your code doesn't run with `M, N = 5, 10`, throwing an error `operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (5,10) (5,5) ` at `w_with_diag_zeros = samples - ...`

Comment: I indeed made a mistake in the code presented here as it is not a copy/paste. I changed it. Thank you for you reply @QuangHoang

Comment: still doesn't run `sigma_th_patterns_broadcast` is not defined.

Comment: That said, your loop on `sigma` is hard to optimized/parallelized.

Comment: Now, it should be good to go. If not, I should take break and apologize for the multiple mistakes. Could you explain why would make it hard ? Could I maybe remove the sigma loop and find another way ? @QuangHoang

Comment: Just to clarify, you did mean to apply `np.diag` twice each time, right?

Comment: @Morton, yes. It is correct

Comment: Add comments to the code to show us what the `shape` is for each variable.  The key to `numpy` speed up is to take full advantage of `broadcasting`, and for that we need a clear idea of how shapes evolve.  If I were to run your code, that's what I'd check first.

Comment: I couldn't come up with a way to vectorize it, given that `w` depends on its past values. Though I did shave a few seconds off the runtime (61s -> 56s). Definitely not the answer you were looking for, but here, on the off-chance it helps a tiny bit: [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1AiDayolfiunyKpNnsjAzh6crlPmU2qza?usp=sharing)

Comment: @Morton, Thank you very much. I will take any seconds that can be removed. More than that, I think your code is cleaner than the original. It is for me more understandable. Furthermore, for me the gains of time is slightly better than yours. I run it with an average of 30sec, which means an average gain of 10s, which is a good improvement at this point. I will check if I can do something else. Thank you !